# How do I constrain the height and width of an image in React Dropzone?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, frontend, react-dropzone

```
<Dropzone onDrop={_aaaa} minSize={1024} maxSize={3072000} maxFiles={5}>
          {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, isDragAccept, isDragReject }) => {
            return (
              <div {...getRootProps({ className: "yyyy" })}>
                <p className="xxxx">Drag the files to this area.</p>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
              </div>
            );
          }}</Dropzone>
```

I just want to upload 400x500 photos.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the image is onload, the function gives me the width and height values.

```
    var image = new Image();    
image.onload = function () {
    console.log('width', image.width);
    console.log('height', image.height);
};
```